# Xamarin spinner SetOnKeyListener not works

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-spinner

I use Xamarin `spinner` in dialog mode. I would like to catch hardware button presses when the `spinner` in an opened state. Finally, I would like to scroll the `spinner` with hardware up and down buttons.

I did it:

in `OnStart():`

```
spinner.SetOnKeyListener(this);
```

I implemented `OnKey()` and `OnKeyUp()`, `OnKeyDown()` methods. After I made three breakpoints in first lines of these three methods. In running state when I press the buttons, breakpoints are not caught but opened `spinner` is scrolled slowly. I don't know what the problem is. Please, give me some advice! Thanks!

Comment: What's you mean "hardware up and down buttons" ?

Comment: I think we'd likely need to see some code to help you pinpoint the problem